# Combine Hash and sum the values in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have below hash:

```
{"shape":[  
  {"key":"0000round","total_amount":"54679110.10","name":"Round","count":100},     
  {"key":"0001square","total_amount":"4074837.00","name":"Square","count":200},
  {"key":"0003rectangle","total_amount":"6114261.00","name":"Rectangle","count":150},
  {"key":"0008round","total_amount":"6425948.50","name":"Round","count":620},
  {"key":"0004square","total_amount":"5009297.50","name":"Square","count":440}
]}
```

I want to sum total amount and count for some duplicate values such as `0000round` and `0008round`.

Here in this case uniq key will be `Name`

so `Name=Round` has 2 values similerly for `Square`.

What I have tried so far:

```
temp_hash = Hash.new(nil)
raw_hash['shape'].each do |shape|
  if temp_hash[shape['name']].present?
    temp_hash[shape['name']]['total_amount'] = temp_hash[shape['name']]['total_amount'].to_f + shape['total_amount'].to_f
    temp_hash[shape['name']]['count'] = temp_hash[shape['name']]['count'].to_i + shape['count'].to_i
    temp_hash[shape['name']]['key'] = [temp_hash[shape['name']]['key'] , shape['key']].flatten    
  else
    temp_hash[shape['name']] = shape
  end

raw_hash['shape'] = temp_hash.values 
end
```

Output is

```
{"shape"=>[
{"key"=>["0000round", "0004round"],"total_amount"=>59688407.6,"name"=>"Round","count"=>7437},
{"key"=>"0001princess","total_amount"=>"4074837.00","name"=>"Princess","count"=>810},
{"key"=>["0003oval", "0008oval"],"total_amount"=>12540209.5,"name"=>"Oval","count"=>1460}]}
```

Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, we are going to define a `Hash` which tells us for each of the keys how the values should be merged:

```ruby
merger = {
  key: -> *values { values },
  total_amount: -> *values { values.sum(&:to_f) },
  count: -> *values { values.sum },
  name: -> *values { values.last }
}
```

It will make sense soon what we use this for.

We need to group the `Hash` by the `:name` key:

```ruby
grouped_hash = raw_hash[:shape].group_by {|h| h[:name] }
```

We only need the values of the resulting `Hash`, not the keys:

```ruby
grouped_hashes = grouped_hash.values
```

We need to transform the values of this `Array` somehow:

```ruby
transformed_hashes = grouped_hashes.map {|hashes| … something … }
```

So, what is `something`? Well, we need to *merge* all `Hash`es in each group, and we need to do this with different functions based on the key. That's why we made our `Hash` of `Proc`s above. So, the `something` looks like this:

```ruby
hashes.reduce {|acc, hash| acc.merge(hash) {|key, *values| merger[key].(*values) }}
```

So, the total result looks like this:

```ruby
merger = {
  key: -> *values { values },
  total_amount: -> *values { values.sum(&:to_f) },
  count: -> *values { values.sum },
  name: -> *values { values.last }
}

raw_hash[:shape].group_by {|h| h[:name] }.
  values.
  map do |hashes|
    hashes.reduce do |acc, hash|
      acc.merge(hash) do |key, *values|
        merger[key].(*values)
      end
    end
  end
```